# destroyWindow (from opencv) closes all windows and stops c++ program

Tags: c++, opencv, window

I'm writing an live video processing program in c++, and want to be able to toggle three windows with the same mjpeg stream, in color, grayscale, and monochrome. I have all the image feeds running, but, since my screen is small, I want to be able to toggle them on and off individually. To do this, I have written the code below, but calling destroyWindow("[windowname]"); stops the whole program, instead. I've already read the documentation, and putting void in front of it doesn't help. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Here's the code (***it's in an infinite loop, until the break you see below is called***):

---

```
    imshow("Color", imageColor);
    imshow("Monochrome", imageMonochrome);
    imshow("Grayscale", imageGrayscale);

    int keyPressed = waitKey(0);
    if (keyPressed > 0)
    {
        cout << keyPressed;
        cout << "key was pressed\n";
        // Press C to toggle color window
        if (99 == keyPressed)
        {
            if (colorOpen)
            {
                cout << "Color window closed\n";
                void destroyWindow("Color");
                colorOpen = false;
            }
            if (!colorOpen)
            {   
                cout << "Color window opened\n";
                imshow("Color", imageColor);
                colorOpen = true;
            }
        }

        // Press M to toggle monochrome window
        if (109 == keyPressed)
        {
            if (monochromeOpen)
            {
                cout << "Monochrome window closed\n";
                void destroyWindow("Monochrome");
                monochromeOpen = false;
            }
            if (!monochromeOpen)
            {
                cout << "Monochrome window opened\n";
                imshow("Monochrome", imagebw);
                monochromeOpen = true;
            }
        }

        // Press G to toggle grayscale window
        if (103 == keyPressed)
        {
            if (grayscaleOpen)
            {
                cout << "Grayscale window closed\n";
                void destroyWindow("Grayscale");
                grayscaleOpen = false;
            }
            if (!grayscaleOpen)
            {
                cout << "Grayscale window opened\n";
                imshow("Grayscale", image);
                grayscaleOpen = true;
            }
        }
        // Break out of infinite loop when [ESC] is pressed:   
        if (27 == keyPressed)
        {
            cout << "Escape Pressed\n";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*I've already read the documentation, and putting void in front of it doesn't help.*" It sounds like you didn't understand what you read. What made you think a `void` there would do anything? What did you think would happen without it?

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted terminates after calling `destroyWindow` (by running off the end of `main`). If that's not what you want to happen, write code that does something else after calling `destroyWindow`. Perhaps you want a loop?

Comment: you may need a loop as @Schwartz said. This may help:   'while (keyPressed > 0) { //blabla;  keyPressed = waitKey(0); }'